# How to redirect a defined ostream from a 3rd party library to a spdlog logger?

Tags: c++, spdlog

I have changed the logging and printout of messages in one of my application by the spdlog library. Everything works within the code that I control. The issue that I faced is that I do not manage to redirect the print out and other error messages from a 3rd party library.

In the library, std::cout and std::cerr are redirected to an intermediate std::ostream named errorOut or printOut, which are defined globally in the library as `extern std::ostream printOut;` and implemented as `std::ostream library::printOut(std::cout.rdbuf());`

I have tried to change the redirected stream to an std::ostringstream : `std::ostringstream ss; library::printOut.rdbuf(ss.rdbuf());`. Then, I used it for a sink of spdlog with `auto sink2 = std::make_shared<spdlog::sinks::ostream_sink_mt> (ss);` and combined it in combined logger.

However doing so, the error messages from the library are not print out in cout/cerr as normally.

Therefore, how to redirect / capture a defined ostream from a library to spdlog without modifying those libraries ?

Thanks for your help and inputs.

Comment: `ostream_sink_mt` is for redirecting spdlog to ostreams, not the other way around. What spdlog call are you trying to translate `printOut << "a" << "b"` to? `info("a"); info("b")`? `info("ab")`?